# Dynamically Insert page title into every page on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I completed all page for my website on Wordpress.

For example.
The title 1: How to build a website on Wordpress
The title 2: How to secure a WP website

Now I want to add this line to all page at the bottom:
"If you have any question on [page title], please give a comment below!"

The result that I'm expecting should be:
Page 1 content:
Step 1
Step 2
If you have any question on How to build a website on Wordpress, please give a comment below!

Page 2 content
Step 1
Step 2
If you have any question on How to secure a WP website, please give a comment below!

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the page content by the `the_content` filter
Have a look at the below code

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_bottom_content' );
function add_bottom_content( $content ) {
    $content .=  "If you have any question on ".get_the_title().", please give a comment below!";
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: It works great. Any way to make it works with Visual Composer in admin panel?

Comment: Yes you can, please check `content_edit_pre` filter https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_edit_pre

Comment: Can you please explain more? I want to use Visual Composer to create above content ("If you have any question on [page title], please give a comment below!") then insert it to every page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the wp function [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/)

> the_title( string $before = '', string $after = '', bool $echo = true )
>
> Display or retrieve the current post title with optional content.

Parameters #Parameters

> $before
>
> ```
> (string) (Optional) Content to prepend to the title.
>
> Default value: ''
> ```
>
> $after
>
> ```
> (string) (Optional) Content to append to the title.
>
> Default value: ''
> ```
>
> $echo
>
> ```
> (bool) (Optional) default to true.Whether to display or return.
>
> Default value: true
> ```

i.e. :

```
the_title("If you have any question on ", ", please give a comment below!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add some php code in your page template.

I use twentysixteen theme as example. In wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/template-parts/content-page.php

add `If you have any question on <?php the_title(); ?>, please give a comment below!` inside the entry-content div.

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php twentysixteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
        the_content();

        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentysixteen' ) . '</span>',
            'after'       => '</div>',
            'link_before' => '<span>',
            'link_after'  => '</span>',
            'pagelink'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentysixteen' ) . ' </span>%',
            'separator'   => '<span class="screen-reader-text">, </span>',
        ) );
        ?>
        If you have any question on <?php the_title(); ?>, please give a comment below!

    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <?php
        edit_post_link(
            sprintf(
                /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
                __( 'Edit<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'twentysixteen' ),
                get_the_title()
            ),
            '<footer class="entry-footer"><span class="edit-link">',
            '</span></footer><!-- .entry-footer -->'
        );
    ?>

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```